# From where does it follow that we have countable many covers for measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that for any bounded set $E$, there is a  $G_\delta$ set $G$ for which $E \subseteq G$ $m^*(G)=m^*(E).$

As $E$ is bounded the outer measure $m^*(E)$ is finite. Thus for any $k \in \Bbb N$ there exists $\{I_{k,n}\}_n$ such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{n} I_{k,n}$.

Let $G_k = \bigcup_{n} I_{k,n}$. Now $G_k$ is an open set for which $$m^*(G_k)\le \sum_{n} \ell(I_{k,n}) \le m^*(E) + \varepsilon. $$

Now define $G:= \bigcap_{k} G_k$, then $G$ is an $G_\delta$ set and for every $k \in \Bbb N$ we have that $E \subset G_k$ we also have that $E \subset G$. Now $$m^*(E) \le m^*(G) \le m^*(G_k) \le m^*(E) + \varepsilon$$ which concludes the proof.

> Question: Where does it follow that we have $k$ many covers for $E$? That is how is it that for any $k \in \Bbb N$ there exists $\{I_{k,n}\}_n$ such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{n} I_{k,n}$?

Comment: What is the difference between $G_1$ and $G_2\,$? between $G_{11}$ and $G_{222}\,$? I see no difference in your construction.

Comment: Say that $E = [0,1]$, then $I_{1,n}$ could be $\{(-1,1), (1/2, 3)\}$ and $I_{2,n} = \{(-2,1), (-1,3)\}$. Now $G_1 = (-1, 3)$ and $G_2=(-2,3)$?

Comment: you should consider a sequence of epsilons, with $\epsilon_j \downarrow 0.$

Comment: What do you mean by sequence of epsilons? I haven't seen this kind of sequence before in measure theory.

Comment: i mean positive real numbers

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you come up with the conclusion that $G_1$ and $G_2$ would be the same?